# witharrows package but with arrows in between equal signs

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, arrows, aligned, witharrows

I am trying to do something very similar to what witharrows package does.
However, while the witharrows package connects two lines of equations with an arrow to the right side of the equations, as the figure below shows,

[image]

I wish to put **vertical arrows in between the equal signs** like the figure shown below.

[image]

Is there anyway to do this? either by making a change to witharrows or defining a new command?
I am pretty new to Latex so I need some guidance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code you have tried so far? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: With `amsmath` you can just do ``& \,\left\downarrow … \right. \\`` for that line with the arrow and the arrow will stretch accordingly.

Comment: Welcome. // To come up with a complete AND concise code example I suggest to extract from your current code and follow this checklist: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . It's pretty fast to do so and will improve both the reply rate and quality of answers to your question. Thank you

Comment: Thank you everyone! I will post the question again with a code snippet to make my point clearer.

Comment: Please only edit this question and add there the code and more remarks ... Asking a new same question is not helpful ...